# include file using array in php

Tags: php

I have two files to be included in the index.php. One is config.php and the other is db.php. I used

```
<?php include 'config.php'
include 'db.php' ?>
```

Tested on a vulnerability scanner rips. It says Userinput reaches sensitive sink. include include ('config.php'). Proof of concept /index.php?file=../../../../../../../etc/passwd.

The suggestion is

```
$files = array("index.php", "main.php");  
if(!in_array($_GET["file"], $ files)) exit;
```

Can you anyone please explain how to add config.php and db.php according the suggestion above?. I have both my files in an include folder.

Can anyone have look at http://cxsecurity.com/issue/WLB-2011040079.

Comment: You shouldn't be passing files to be included in your querystring.

Comment: I don't see how the code and the suggestion are related in any way at all.

Comment: so what's happening in config.php? just `include()`ing a file on your server should NOT trigger a vulnerability, unless that included file is doing something stupid.

Comment: Did you leave out a semicolon after the first include() statement?

Comment: he's blankly including connection string information in config and db and then including that on his index page.

Comment: @MarcB config.php has some basic defines. The db as usual is the database connector. I believe there is nothing stupid in it. Tested the script on rips php vulnerability scanner and it says what I wrote above. It suggest me to use array for including config.php and db.php which I have never done before.

Comment: @davidhaskins no sir, that was typo. It has the semicolon at the end of both includes.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit I searched google regarding the include using arrays. Google has a few site showing how it can be done. I asked for help because somehow I could not get the concept clearly.

Comment: @user3639541: Either you replied to the wrong comment or you didn't understand mine.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit can u please have a look at http://cxsecurity.com/issue/WLB-2011040079

Comment: Okay I looked at it now what

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you seem to be upset .... Thanks for responding and am sorry if I upset you

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion you received is that you hard-code a list of valid values for `$_GET['file']` and then check user input against that list. If you'd like to allow additional files, simply add them to the list:

```
$files = array("index.php","main.php","config.php","db.php");
```

I'm not sure if this will help you pass whatever vulnerability test you are running, but it will ensure that only files you deliberately list will be included.

Comment: @oliakoil I'll try your suggestion and get back to you. Thank you for your suggestion.